# Slide-Menu + multiple ViewControllers (Swift)

Tags: swift

http://www.raywenderlich.com/87268/3d-effect-taasky-swift

I implemented into my project but I have some questions , as I am relatively new to Swift.
With this kind of arrangement how can I present different ViewControllers after a different MenuItem is pressed ?
I cant perform a segue , because it covers the entire screen and I want to keep the Menu-Detail.
I tried with .hidden Views , but it seems the wrong way to go.
Thx in advance